# ¿Cómo validar una celda en QTableWidget?

Tags: validación, eventos, pyqt, pyqt4

Trabajo con `pyqt4` en `python3.4` y quiero validar si el text en la celda es un float y capturar el evento de cuanto es introducido, me explico, cuando un elemento en la tabla sea modificado o añadido quiero modificar una variable booleana que tengo. ¿Cómo lo hago?

Answer (score 0):

Se me ocurre que puedes conectarte al evento de cambio de la celda, por ejemplo:

```
TablaWidget.itemChanged.connect(self.celda_change)
```

Luego creas el método para procesar este cambio:

```
def celda_change(self, current, previous):
   pass
```

Para validar si lo ingresado es un "float", lo que haría es simplemente convertir el texto a float y controlar la excepción, por ejemplo:

```
def number_float(s):

    try:
        n = float(s) # for int, long and float
    except ValueError:
        return None

    return n
```

Si el retorno es `None` lo ingresado no es consistente con un `float`